# LuaBridge and Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, lua, luabridge

I'm trying to pass an object by a base class pointer from C++ to Lua using LuaBridge. Both the derived and base class are registered with LuaBridge correctly.

On the C++ side:

```
// Assume both Foo and FooBase are registered properly with LuaBridge,
// exposing the a, b, and c properties

struct FooBase
{
    int a;
    // ...
};

struct Foo : public FooBase
{
    int b;
    int c;
    // ...
};

// ... other code ...

void Bar(const FooBase* foo)
{
    // Assume that 'foo' is a pointer to a valid 'Foo' object
    luabridge::LuaRef ref = luabridge::getGlobal(L, "bar");
    ref(foo);
}
```

On the Lua side:

```
function bar(foo)
    foo.a -- This is ok
    foo.b -- This is nil
end
```

How can I 'cast-down' from `FooBase*` to `Foo*` in Lua? Does Lua/LuaBridge even support this?

Answer (score 3):

Probably not and the need to do so **could** show a design mistake in your code. Preform the cast in C++, you know far more about the types than Lua does, so that either the function Bar accepts a Foo* or does the downcast before calling the function.